# O significado de "em caso de" ou "caso"

Tags: significado, português-brasileiro, gramática

Existe diferença de significado entre ***no caso de*** e ***caso***?

Sei que gramaticamente, sim, eles são diferentes. Mas e quanto ao significado?

Por exemplo:

> Vamos encomendar mais salgadinhos e docinhos no caso de ele vir com a família toda.
>
> Caso ele venha com a família toda vamos encomendar mais salgadinhos e docinhos.

Os dois estão dizendo a mesma coisa, ou seja: Se ele vier com a família toda, depois encomendamos mais salgadinhos e docinhos.

Mais um exemplo:

> Leve o mapa da cidade no caso de não conseguir encontrar a pousada.
>
> Leve o mapa da cidade caso não consiga encontrar a pousada.

Nesse exemplo, a pessoa primeiro leva o mapa que talvez depois possa precisar.

Está certo? Ou seja, *caso* tem significados diferentes nesses exemplos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim, no exemplo dos “salgadinhos e docinhos”, se o significado pretendido é

> Se ele vier com a família toda, depois encomendamos mais salgadinhos e docinhos

Podes usar *caso* ou *no caso de:*

> **No caso de** ele vir com a família toda, vamos encomendar mais salgadinhos e docinhos
> **Caso** ele venha com a família toda, vamos encomendar mais salgadinhos e docinhos
>
> Vamos encomendar mais salgadinhos e docinhos **no caso de** ele vir com a família toda
> Vamos encomendar mais salgadinhos e docinhos **caso** ele venha com a família toda

Geralmente, é mais comum começar com *no caso de*/*caso* (duas primeiras versões acima) do que com o *vamos encomendar*. Como observaste, a gramática é diferente: *no caso de* pede um infinitivo pessoal (*no caso de ele vir, no caso de eles virem*); *caso* pede um subjuntivo (*caso ele venha, caso eles venham*).

Os exemplos do “mapa” soam estranhos aos meus ouvidos de falante de português europeu. Para o significado que tu pretendes:

> Leve o mapa da cidade, porque poderá precisar dele

Eu usaria ***para o caso de**:*

> Leve o mapa da cidade **para o caso de** não conseguir encontrar a pousada

Porque se usares *no caso de* ou *caso* a minha interpretação seria como nos exemplos dos “docinhos e salgadinhos”: ’se você não conseguir encontrar a pousada, leve o mapa’. É claro que esta interpretação não faz muito sentido, e eu pensaria que a pessoa talvez quisesse dizer *para o caso de* e se tivesse enganado.

Comment: Deves fazer uma nota que estás a explicar português europeu, Jacinto, porque a pergunta é explicitamente sobre português brasileiro.

Comment: Eu inicialmente entendi "compro mais salgadinhos no caso de virem muitos" como "compro já mais, não vá acontecer virem muitos", e a outra frase "compro mais salgadinhos caso venham muitos" como "se vierem muitos, então [nessa altura] compro mais". E acho esta uma leitura plausível. Mas fizeste-me pensar sobre isto, e acho que a leitura que fizeste é também adequada. :)

Comment: @ANevesthinksSEisevil, para mim *no caso de* = *se*: "compro no caso de virem" = "compro se vierem" = "compro caso venham". Compro antes para estar preparado, para mim é "compro para o caso de virem". Eu sei que o que faria talvez sentido fazer numa situação real seria comprar antes para o caso de eles virem, e vi alguns exemplos em que *no caso de* aparecia onde eu escreveria *para o caso de*, mas pareceu-me escrita descuidada ou até talvez traduções mal feitas: havia um "somente no caso de" que cheira a tradução de "just in case" (que é 'para o caso de').